# Strimzi Kafka authentication/authorization

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

i'm trying to create a user resource through user operator which can be used for clients to connect to kafka. i'm also implementing authorization as well.

following is my kafka-resource file.

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.2.1
    replicas: 1
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: scram-sha-512
    authorization:
      type: simple
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 1Gi
        cpu: 0.4
      limits:
        memory: 1Gi
        cpu: 0.5
    template:
      pod:
        tolerations:
          - key: "kubernetes.azure.com/scalesetpriority"
            operator: "Equal"
            value: "spot"
            effect: "NoSchedule"
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 1
      default.replication.factor: 1
      min.insync.replicas: 1
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.1"
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
    metricsConfig:
      type: jmxPrometheusExporter
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: kafka-metrics
          key: kafka-metrics-config.yml
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 1
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
    metricsConfig:
      type: jmxPrometheusExporter
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: kafka-metrics
          key: zookeeper-metrics-config.yml
  kafkaExporter:
    topicRegex: ".*"
    groupRegex: ".*"
```

and below is my user-resource file

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaUser
metadata:
  name: kafka-user1
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-cluster
spec:
  authentication:
    type: "scram-sha-512"
  authorization:
    type: "simple"
    acls:
      - resource:
          type: "topic"
          name: "sit-*"
          patternType: "prefix"
        operation: "Read"
      - resource:
          type: "topic"
          name: "sit-*"
          patternType: "prefix"
        operation: "Write"
      - resource:
          type: "topic"
          name: "sit-*"
          patternType: "prefix"
        operation: "Create"
      - resource:
          type: "topic"
          name: "sit-*"
          patternType: "prefix"
        operation: "Describe"
```

problem is

1. i do see a user-resource being created but it never goes into READY state

> $ kubectl get kafkauser.kafka.strimzi.io -n kafka

> NAME          CLUSTER      AUTHENTICATION   AUTHORIZATION   READY

> kafka-user1  my-cluster   scram-sha-512    simple

2. i don't see any secrets being created

> $ kubectl get secret -n kafka
> NAME                                TYPE                 DATA   AGE
> kafka-user-auth                     Opaque               2      54d
> my-cluster-clients-ca               Opaque               1      5m55s
> my-cluster-clients-ca-cert          Opaque               3      5m55s
> my-cluster-cluster-ca               Opaque               1      5m55s
> my-cluster-cluster-ca-cert          Opaque               3      5m55s
> my-cluster-cluster-operator-certs   Opaque               4      5m55s
> my-cluster-kafka-brokers            Opaque               4      5m32s
> my-cluster-kafka-exporter-certs     Opaque               4      4m59s
> my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes          Opaque               4      5m54s
> sh.helm.release.v1.strimzi.v1       helm.sh/release.v1   1      61d

NOTE: please ignore `kafka-user-auth` secret, it's a different one.

here's a kubectl describe on the user-resource

```
Name:         kafka-user1
Namespace:    kafka
Labels:       strimzi.io/cluster=my-cluster
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
Kind:         KafkaUser
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-05-16T15:50:56Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
        f:labels:
          .:
          f:strimzi.io/cluster:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:authentication:
          .:
          f:type:
        f:authorization:
          .:
          f:acls:
          f:type:
    Manager:         kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2023-05-16T15:50:56Z
  Resource Version:  26514057
  UID:               6131c71a-7fa9-4de5-9a5e-59970f346faa
Spec:
  Authentication:
    Type:  scram-sha-512
  Authorization:
    Acls:
      Operation:  Read
      Resource:
        Name:          sit-*
        Pattern Type:  prefix
        Type:          topic
      Operation:       Write
      Resource:
        Name:          sit-*
        Pattern Type:  prefix
        Type:          topic
      Operation:       Create
      Resource:
        Name:          sit-*
        Pattern Type:  prefix
        Type:          topic
      Operation:       Describe
      Resource:
        Name:          sit-*
        Pattern Type:  prefix
        Type:          topic
    Type:              simple
Events:                <none>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Kafka` resource does not enable the User Operator -> without that there is nobody to handle the `KafkaUser` resource, create the user and password, and make it ready. So you have to enable it. You can check the examples https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/blob/main/examples/kafka/kafka-persistent.yaml#L40 or the docs: https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/deploying.html#deploying-the-topic-operator-using-the-cluster-operator-str

Comment: that helped @Jakub, is it possible to configure kafka in a way that it only use username/password based authentication while still communicating over tls. i don't want certificate verification. is it possible that the client only provides username/password and is able to connect to kafka.

Comment: I don't think the Kafka client can be configured to ignore the server certificate. So I think you would need to disable the TLS for that completely.

Comment: so what security.protocol i should be using in case both username/pass and ssl authentication is enabled when connecting client to broker? SASL_SSL or only SSL?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood ... Strimzi does not support mTLS and SCRAM-SHA combined. It is one or the other. You can use SCRAM-SHA with TLS encryption and server authentication. SCRAM-SHA with TLS encryption would be SASL_SSL protocol. mTLS alone would be SSL.

Comment: when using SASL_SSL,am i only using username/pass authentication or do i have to provide certs as well

Comment: With the config you shared above, you will have to provide a truststore with the public key of the CA -> you can get it from the `my-cluster-cluster-ca-cert` secret.